# how can I compare one int element with a list int

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to compare my list with one id element in a query, I do this for my school but I don't know how.

```
List<int> list = (from d in db.Desv 
                  where d.LastDesvId != null 
                  select d.DesvId).ToList();

ViewBag.Desv = new SelectList(db.Desv
                                 .Where(x => x.state.Equals("Proc") && x.DesvId != list)
                                 .OrderBy(y => y.DesviacionId), "Id", "Id");
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  See if a specific int is in the list?

Comment: `lista` is this a typo? What is `lista` here?

Comment: yes the specific int should be in list

Comment: FirstOrDefault?

Comment: You can use `.Contains()` here `!list.Contains(x.DesvId)`.

Comment: @ProgramadorS Do you just want to know if its in the list?  Or do you want to extract something from the list?  You need to be more clear

Comment: Where is the int value that you want to compare? I see only lists

Comment: I agree with @maccettura. The solution which I have provided you may not be the one you are looking for. Until and unless you provide us with some more details no one over here will be able to help you.

Comment: yes i try to know if list contains the int so i can excluded

Comment: x.DesvId != list should not compile: you are tryng to compare a list against an int value (assuming that)

Comment: where is the int? the scalar variable that's containing a single int you are tryng to compare?

Comment: @GianlucaConte yes i don't know how compare with each element in list is why i only put list in the query 
i try to do that x.Desv != each element of list

Comment: Ok so you want a function that returns true if Desv contains all the elements of the list  'list'?

Comment: i want to know to dont´t use it in the viewBag

Comment: No matter viewBag now. I'ts just a "property container". Focus on what kind of result you espect from the query: a list? an int? a bool?

Comment: i espect a list from that but only the list that dont contains the same int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contains(T element) returns true if element is in the list, else false. So the code you want is:

```
            List<int> list = (from d in db.Desv
                          where d.LastDesvId != null
                          select d.DesvId).ToList();

        ViewBag.Desv = new SelectList(db.Desv
                                         .Where(x => x.state.Equals("Proc") && !list.Contains(x.DesvId))
                                         .OrderBy(y => y.DesviacionId), "Id", "Id");
```